# Magento update order shipping address

Tags: php, magento

At the end of the purchase, the user has the possibility to change your shipping address. Im trying to update this information, but it dosen't work. This is my code:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrder();
$postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();

$_new_address = array (
    'firstname' => $postData['nombre'],
    'lastname'  => $postData['apellidos'],
    'street'    => array ('0' => $postData['direccion']),
    'city'      => $postData['localidad'],
    'region_id' => $postData['provincia_id'],
    'region'    => '',
    'postcode'  => $postData['codigo_postal'],
    'country_id'=> 'ES',
    'telephone' => $postData['telefono']
);

$customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
$customAddress->setData($_new_address)
    ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
    ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
    ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
    ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

// Save address
try {
    $customAddress->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
    header('Location: /');
    exit;
}

// Update the order
try {
    $order->setShippingAddress($customAddress)->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
    header('Location: /');
    exit;
}
```

Can I update an order or is not allowed? Can anyone give me a tip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was that the Billing address and shipping address in the order, are different than having the user has as default addresses.

At the end the code looks like this:

```
$order = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrder();

$postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();

// Try to get shipping and billing address data.
$orderShippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();
$orderShipping = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($orderShippingAddress);

$orderBillingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress()->getId();
$orderBilling = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($orderBillingAddress);

// Updating data.
$orderShipping->addData($postData);
$orderBilling->addData($postData);

try {
    $orderShipping->implodeStreetAddress()->save();
    $orderBilling->implodeStreetAddress()->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::logException($e);
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
    header('Location: /after/success/envio');
    exit;
}
```

Now, it works. Thanks for your help @R.S

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to update the shipping address for an order, take a look @ `addressSaveAction()` in /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php

```
$order = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrder();

//Get shipping address Id
$addressId = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();

$address    = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($addressId);

$data       = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

$address->addData($data);

$address->implodeStreetAddress()->save();
```

Also i'm not sure if `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrder()` will still contain a  valid order id after you submit your form since you will be loading a new page

Comment: Yes, getLastOrder() still contain a valid order id.

Answer (score 2):

While functioning correctly both other answers have an excessive address loading. The `getShippingAddress` already returns instance of `sales/order_address`. So the procedure can be simplified to following:

```
$order = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrder();
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

$order->getShippingAddress()->addData($data)
    ->save();
```

Also `implodeStreetAddress` method call only required if you use multiline street address.